# Django/Jinja: "Unused is at end of expression"

Tags: python, django, jinja2

I'm getting a weird Django error when accessing the following jinja template:

```
{% if variable is defined %}
    value of variable: {{ variable }}
{% else %}
    variable is not defined
{% endif %}
```

It is very basic and taken from the original [documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#defined). `variable` is not defined nor ever mentioned. Any ideas what might cause this issue?

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://    
Django Version: 1.9.7
Python Version: 3.4.2
Installed Applications:
['medisearch',
 'mediwiki',
 'crispy_forms',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template /home/django/mediwiki/medisearch/templates/medisearch/response.html, error at line 1
   Unused 'is' at end of if expression.   1 :  {% if variable is defined %} 
   2 :     value of variable: {{ variable }}
   3 : {% else %}
   4 :     variable is not defined
   5 : {% endif %}
   6 : 

Traceback:

File "/home/django/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/django/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/django/mediwiki/medisearch/views.py" in search
  21.             return render(request, 'medisearch/response.html', {'response': response})

File "/home/django/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in render
  67.             template_name, context, request=request, using=using)

File "/home/django/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  96.             template = get_template(template_name, using=using)

File "/home/django/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in get_template
  32.                 return engine.get_template(template_name, dirs)

File "/home/django/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in get_template
  40.             return Template(self.engine.get_template(template_name, dirs), self)

File "/home/django/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/engine.py" in get_template
  190.         template, origin = self.find_template(template_name, dirs)

File "/home/django/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/engine.py" in find_template
  157.                         name, template_dirs=dirs, skip=skip,

File "/home/django/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/loaders/base.py" in get_template
  46.                     contents, origin, origin.template_name, self.engine,

File "/home/django/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in __init__
  189.         self.nodelist = self.compile_nodelist()

File "/home/django/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in compile_nodelist
  231.             return parser.parse()

File "/home/django/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in parse
  516.                     raise self.error(token, e)

File "/home/django/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in parse
  514.                     compiled_result = compile_func(self, token)

File "/home/django/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in do_if
  1027.     condition = TemplateIfParser(parser, bits).parse()

File "/home/django/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/smartif.py" in parse
  201.                                    self.current_token.display())

Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError at /medisearch/
Exception Value: Unused 'is' at end of if expression.
```

Comment: Did you modify your `TEMPLATES` list in the `settings.py` to contain the `jinja2 BACKEND`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess it that this is happening because Django isn't fully compatible with Jinja2. This is taken from the [Jinja FAQ](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/faq/#how-compatible-is-jinja2-with-django):

> The default syntax of Jinja2 matches Django syntax in many ways. However this similarity doesn’t mean that you can use a Django template unmodified in Jinja2. For example filter arguments use a function call syntax rather than a colon to separate filter name and arguments. Additionally the extension interface in Jinja is fundamentally different from the Django one which means that your custom tags won’t work any longer.

Granted, I'm not sure if this is why it isn't working for you.

However, [the Django documentation suggests using the `{% if %}` template tag to check for definedness](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#if) (definitely a word):

> The {% if %} tag evaluates a variable, and if that variable is “true” (i.e. exists, is not empty, and is not a false boolean value) the contents of the block are output

What is important to you here is the "i.e. exists".

My best guess is that because of this, Jinja in Django does not use the `defined` function, because you are supposed to just use the `{% if %}` tag.

Please do note, however, that this is not the behavior in regular Python:

```
if variable:
    print(variable)

# NameError: name 'variable' is not defined
```

Comment: Huh, I never knew that Django didn't use Jinja by default! Originally, I wanted to use Jinjas `iterable` function to check whether a variable is iterable/ a list. Is this possible with Django's template language? If not, is it worth switching to Jinja?

Comment: I've used both, and don't particularly prefer one over the other. In general, I try to refactor my code every few commits so that there isn't so much logic in the template, because I am a big believer in separation of logic and design. If you really like Django and don't see yourself using anything else, then you could stick with the Django template unless for some reason it becomes severely limiting (which I don't expect). The advantage of learning Jinja, however, is that it is used by other frameworks, such as Flask, and thus is good to know if you plan on working on other stuff.

Comment: All in all, they're not too different IMO

Answer (score 0):

The error is because Django is treating your template as Django template language. Your jinja2 templates belong in your app's `jinja2` directory, e.g. `/home/django/mediwiki/medisearch/jinja2/medisearch/response.html`